# Android send data other thread queue

Tags: java, android

I want to generate some text string that is going to be sent via TCP socket . I have accomplished it within few minutes. 
However I want a producer consumer pattern.I dont care if it failed or not.
Should I create a Blocking Queque at application for this ? Should I create a service ?
Note that I want a single thread to manage this job.

Comment: Is this task a "short" task, meaning short it starts, does its job and then ends? Is it unknown in time, or maybe even of forever duration?

Comment: If there is network connectivity it takes about 30 - 1000ms max.If there is a problem if retries some times. But I want to discard it after some retries for now

Answer (score 1):

In the case it's a short task (like you commented), I'd recommend putting it within an `AsyncTask` as a background thread. You can control anything about this separately, which will help you also debugging it. `Services` are more intended for long executing tasks, so I'd not recommend it at this scope (it's a bit harder even to communicate with other `Activity`'s. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) you'll find the `AsyncTask`'s documentation, and here a [good example](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.UuKXkrRMXIU).

The Blocking structure depends on your needs - but I don't think you'll need that in your case. Anyway, if you would need that, there're lots of thread-safe data structures you may use, you might find [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) helpful.

Comment: Hm so asynctask would run even I exit the activity ? Hm I think that this might not work as I need because if something is being sent server blocks other tcp incoming connections so it would miserably fail. Ideally I would like a centralised approach.

Comment: @Parhs What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: AsyncTask are threads in fact, so it will run until it has to run, independently of your activity. It's started, does its work, and exits. As they're threads, you are not blocking anything, you may define an incoming socket and an outgoing one, both working at the same time (I use this in many apps). You may declare as many tcp sockets as you want as far as you have enough bandwith to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `LinkedBlockingQueue` where your producer adds data. Create a `Timer` that fires every second or so. The task of the `Timer` would be to send the messages over the wire.

For this, both the producer (the one generating the messages) and consumer (`Timer`) should have access to the `LinkedBlockingQueue`.  The `Timer` will remove the first element of the `LinkedBlockingQueue` and then send it.

Sounds good ?

Comment: Sounds actually not very good. An `ArrayList` is neither intended to be shared across threads nor to be used in producer-consumer patterns unlike e.g. [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)

Comment: @zapl I am a learner myself. I should use a `LinkedBlockingQueue` instead of `ArrayList` ? Rest stays the same ? =)

Comment: Yes because that's what BlockingQueues are made for. They allow any thread to queue up (produce) data that another (or even multiple) consumer threads receive. And they are threadsafe. With `ArrayList` you would have to do a lot of complex synchronization to get it as safe and as fast. Essentially any subclass mentioned here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html should work.

Comment: @zapl haha ! I came here to answer someone else's question and learned something new myself !!